# How do i do this in a trigger SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, triggers

The first line seems to be correct. The second line was my SQLite code. With code i get an exception about an error near trigger. In VS it says the multipart identifier could not be bound. With SQLite the new stands for the row being insert. So i would like to increase the count of whomever the subscription recipient is. How do i do that with a SQL Server trigger?

```
CREATE TRIGGER  trig_0  ON  subscription   
 AFTER INSERT  AS  
UPDATE user_data 
   SET msg_count = msg_count + 1 
 WHERE id = new.recipient;
```

Comment: My recommendation would be to use a view, and have `msg_count` as a computed column based on using the `COUNT` aggregate function...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no magic 'new' in SQL Server. There is a magic INSERTED, and is a table:

```
CREATE TRIGGER  trig_0  ON  subscription   
 AFTER INSERT  AS  
UPDATE user_data 
   SET msg_count = msg_count + 1 
FROM user_data
JOIN INSERTED ON id = INSERTED.recipient;
```

Answer (score 1):

i think there is `inserted and delted` tables used by the trigger not new '''

```
3> CREATE TRIGGER myTriggerINSERT
4> ON Employee
5> FOR INSERT
6> AS
7> DECLARE @ID int, @Name nvarchar(30)
8>
9> SET @ID = (SELECT ID FROM inserted)
10> SET @Name = (SELECT Name FROM inserted)
```

for more detail : http://www.java2s.com/Code/SQLServer/Trigger/Getvaluefromupdatedinsertedanddeleted.htm

Comment: This is a very bad coding practice, insert 2 rows in your batch and your trigger blows up, please read http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBProgramming/MSSQLServer/best-practice-coding-sql-server-triggers

Comment: this is just example to show that there is inserted table used by sql trigger not new

Answer (score 0):

assuming subscription  has the column recipient which you can join with user_data.id, here is one way, you can use the inserted pseudo table to join back

```
CREATE TRIGGER  trig_0  ON  subscription   
 AFTER INSERT  AS  
UPDATE user_data 
   SET msg_count = msg_count + 1 
 WHERE exists (Select * from inserted i where user_data.id = inserted.recipient)
```